# MySQL Stored Procedure Call from SSRS through ODBC

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, odbc, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to call a stored procedure that takes one parameter on Mysql from `ssrs`.  Connecting through `ODBC`. I use following syntax for calling using `query designer`:

```
`CALL test.ClientSelectExtract(?)`
```

And I'm getting following error.

```
`SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters`
```

Comment: Unless things are different when using MySQL, I think you should use the `@ParameterName` instead of `?`.

Comment: I tried that and it was sending empty string to the procedure, but when i used it against ordinary statements it works fine

Comment: What do the settings for your SSRS parameter look like? What is the data type? How are you setting the (available/default) values? Note that SSRS will replace `@ParamName` with the actual value (or a csv of the values, if it's a multi-valued parameter) before executing, it doesn't treat it as a proper parameter to the query.

Comment: SSRS parameters i'm using are date time, but formatted them in string in the format of YYY-MM-DD.
SSRS didn't create the parameter automatically so i manually create the params with the same name, as a test the stored proc was to display the params received but i get empty strings

Comment: Okay, but what about the other details? Note that it's possible (even recommended) to add such additional info to the question, instead of comments. You can edit your own questions at any time (which -if substantial- also bumbs your question so more people may view it).

Comment: I think the issue is Mysql specific as it tried the same code with data stored on MSSQL and i get the desired results :(

Comment: I found the solution.
Read from an article ODBC don't support named parameters.
So i called the stored proc as so.
   
 `CALL test.ClientSelectExtract(?)`

Then added a parameter name parameter1 to reference the ?, if i had more ? placeholders the next param would be parameter2 and so on.

then explicitly create a parameter named parameter1 to and set the type and value.

Thanks Jeroen

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. Don't forget you can answer your own question, and accept the answer after 24hrs - which will help future visitors that land here via searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Read from an article that MySql ODBC don't support named parameters. 
So I called the stored proc like this 
  `CALL test.ClientSelectExtract(?)`  
Added a parameter named parameter1 in the Parameters Folders then set the type and value, then explicitly created a parameter named parameter1  to reference the ? on the dataset also, then all worked fine.

Note: If I had more ? placeholders the next param would be parameter2, same steps and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should create linked server in SSMS from MYSQL then only we will call the stored procedure. syntax to call stored procedure:

EXEC ('CALL GASP_sales_aps(?, ?)', @dt_start, @dt_end)AT MySQL(Linked Server Name)

GASP_sales_aps ---->procedure Name

(@dt_start,@dt_end)------> are parameters .